# Changing mysql DATADIR in Windows

Tags: mysql, windows

I'm trying to run `LOAD DATA INFILE` commands on Windows, but I can't figure out how to change DATADIR from `/var/lib/mysql/`

Running through the command line client, my target is:

`"Path_to_sql" "--defaults-file=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini" "-uUser" "-pPassword"`

My my.ini file has the following line:
`datadir=C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\`. I've tried without the trailing double back slash, and with single back slash as well.

When I try LOAD DATA INFILE commands, my path is simply appended to the unchanged default:
`Can't get stat of /var/lib/mysql/DB/path_to_file`.

Additionally,

`SELECT * FROM information_schema.GLOBAL_VARIABLES WHERE variable_name = "DATADIR";`

Returns the default value.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the full path in your statement?

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\data.txt' INTO TABLE my_db.my_table;
```

Comment: Yes, I am using the full file. In your case I get `/var/lib/mysql/DB/C:/Users/Me/Desktop/data.txt`

Comment: I read somewhere to put the path like this: load data local infile "c:/users/ramon/desktop/1.csv"